# How can I use a string as a delimiter in the String.Split() method?

Tags: c#, string, split

```
var playerBeginMarker = "splitHere!";
string[] playerInfoSet = endgameStats.Split(playerBeginMarker, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I'd like to split the endgameStats string, using that playerBeginMarker as the delimiter but it seems to only accept a char.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this `.Split()` overload:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}", "moofoobar".Split(new string[] {"o"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: So the overload doesn't accept a single string, but an ARRAY of strings.

Comment: Yes. There's also `Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)` alias.

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.Split Method (String(), StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx).  You would use a `String` array with one element within - the string you wish to split on.

So it would be:

```
String[] output =  String.Split(new String[]{"splitHere!"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```